# How to change the behavior of indenting the new line after comma in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, indentation, python-idle, visual-studio-code

I am a fresh python programmer. I started using VS Code because of its built-in terminal. (Before that I was using IDLE as an editor.)

My problem is, when I writing the code below in **IDLE**, all I need to do is to **press enter** to indent the new line to **align** with the previous variable.

```
someFunction(longVariable,
             longString,
             longWhatever)
```

In VS Code, it does this when I press enter:

```
someFunction(longVariable,
longString,
longWhatever)
```

Funny thing is when I align the *"longString*" by myself, It goes to the exact point where I want it to be as I press enter after comma. Like this:

```
someFunction(longVariable,
             longString,
             longWhatever)
```

How can I make it behave like IDLE?
I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to installing the `ms-python` extension that @TheDude suggested, I had to install a formatter. The options are [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8), [YAPF](https://github.com/google/yapf), and [Black](https://github.com/ambv/black). Here are the install commands (you only need one of them, I chose YAPF because I was getting weird results with autopep8):

```
pip install yapf

pip install autopep8

pip install black
```

Now, I could not get it working that it would auto-format when I return a line. There is a User Setting parameter called `editor.formatOnType` which I thought would take care of this, but it seems to have no effect. BUT, there is also a User Setting parameter called `editor.formatOnSave` that auto-formats your file every time you save it. If you change this in your user settings `"editor.formatOnSave": true` then every time you save your file, it gets auto-formatted.

You can also use the auto-formatting hotkeys and it will have the same effect:

- Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
- Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Install the `ms-python` Extension.

This offers linting, intellisense, and code-formatting. I'm not sure if it's exactly like IDLE but I've been using it for Python development for several months and it does right by me.

1. Click this button [image]
2. The enter `Python` in the search box and press `enter`
3. The Extension published by Microsoft is the one I recommend